# Django filter by brand

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

im making an ecommerce website with django and im having problems with the filter, I want to show all the brands that I choose.
Here is the view:

```
marca = request.GET.get('marca')

if marca == 'marca':
    products = products.filter (brand__name = marca)
```

marca is Brand.

here is the template:

```
{% for brand in q %}
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{brand.brand}}" name="marca" value="{{brand.brand}}" {% if marca == '{{brand.brand}}' %} checked="checked" {%endif%}>
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{brand.brand}}">{{brand.brand}}</label>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

okay so, its showing me with the filter, but only the last one that I checked. If i check 2 brands, it only showing up the last one. So pls i need some help with this:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of the [**`.get(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get). You can use [**`.getlist(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to obtain the list of all selected brands:

```
products = products.filter(brand__name__in=request.GET.getlist('marca'))
```

You can work with the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) to check if the name is in the list of brands.

It is however odd that you check `marca == 'marca'`. This would only filter in case that the *value* of `marca` is the string `marca`.

Comment: That check marca == 'marca' its there if there is anything checked if its not just dont do it. Do you suggest to change that?

Comment: @AlexCuadra: but that would only filter if `marca` is exactly the value `'marca'`. You can check this with `if marca` (so no `== 'marca'`).

Comment: Okay thanks i changed it, but it keeps showing me only the last brand that i checked:(

Comment: @AlexCuadra: well likely you filter somewhere else as well. Since the `marca == 'marca'` is never true (except when the brand *name* would be `marca`. But since this is a view snippet, it is hard to tell.

Comment: Yeah mb, i had another line where i wrote that, but now it works, thank you so much!